# SSIS Package Failing when called through DTExec - fine through VS

Tags: ssis, dtexec

I have an SSIS package that is running fine when I press the "Start" button in VS, but when I run it via DTExec, it's bombing part way through with the following errors.

```html
Error: 2020-06-10 13:47:20.22
   Code: 0xC0047038
   Source: JCMAST to SQL SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on JCMAST - WA returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
End Error
Error: 2020-06-10 13:47:20.49
   Code: 0xC0047022
   Source: JCMAST to SQL SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Co, Job Yesterday Sort" (47) failed with error code 0xC0047020 while processing input "Sort Input" (50). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
End Error
```

I can see that the package is called properly, as I can see all of the different validation and pre-execution steps. These are the only errors that come up in the entire run.

Everything that I've Googled so far with these errors typically come with some sort of additional error. Not the case here.

What's so confusing to me is why it would run manually, but not through cmd.

EDIT: Full error output

```html
Started:  2:55:09 PM
Error: 2020-06-10 14:55:14.35
   Code: 0xC0047038
   Source: JCMAST to SQL SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on JCMAST - WA returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
End Error
Error: 2020-06-10 14:55:14.64
   Code: 0xC0047022
   Source: JCMAST to SQL SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Co, Job Yesterday Sort" (47) failed with error code 0xC0047020 while processing input "Sort Input" (50). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
End Error
Error: 2020-06-10 14:55:20.67
   Code: 0xC0047038
   Source: EMP Files to SQL SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on PREMP - WA returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  2:55:09 PM
Finished: 2:55:34 PM
Elapsed:  24.343 seconds
```

```html
SSIS package "D:\SafetyServicesProjects\WebAppsTest2\WebAppsTest2\Package.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x80049304 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0047038 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB Destination" wrote 0 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: Data Flow Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "D:\SafetyServicesProjects\WebAppsTest2\WebAppsTest2\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

[image: Control Flow View]

[image: Data Flow View on "JCMAST to SQL"]

[image: Connection Manager]

[image: Test Flow Data Snippet]

Comment: Just added the entire output after putting in the /REP E on. Only additional error is the exact same thing on a different data flow task.

Comment: Huh, I'm expecting to see something like "To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard edition of Integration Services or higher". What can you tell us about the package - what connections are in it, how are you running it from the command line, etc?

Comment: That's what's so confusing to me too. I'm expecting more information...the package uses OLE DB and ODBC connections, combines the data, and puts the data in SQL via OLE DB. The command line is just the classic "..\DTExec.exe" /f "Filename". Looking at the errors, they're coming in on the control flow tasks that have the ODBC connectors, but the components that are giving the errors are OLE DB sources.

Comment: ODBC driver - any chance it's a 32 or 64 bit and you're using the "wrong" dtexec? Along with that train of thought - do you have multiple versions of SSIS installed? Is this package or project deployment model? If Project, are you using project resources like Project connection manager, project parameters etc?

Comment: ODBC driver is set as a system DSN, 64-bit. Running 64-Bit dtexec as well. Just for fun, tried the 32, same errors. This is a brand new VM, only one version of SSIS installed (and everything for that matter). I'd have to say package deployment? Not sure what the project is, so I'm guessing I'm not using that. Just created the solution, saved it, and running through dtexec

Comment: Default will be project deployment model. Brand new VM, you say. What if you create a Hello World level package and try running that from the command line. Like maybe just your Truncate table Execute SQL Task. Also, if you don't mind, pop a screenshot of your Connection Managers - either from the bottom of the SSIS package or check the "Connection Managers" section under the solution/project node in Visual Studio - anything listed there?

Comment: Or you can just roll the dice and try a permutation of this `DTEXEC.exe /Package MyPackage.dtsx /Project "C:\tmp\MyProject\bin\Development\MyProject.ispac"`

Comment: Okay, so I've updated the post with the connection manager screenshot, and by doing a couple smaller test projects it looks like the ODBC connection is the problem. Using the other two connections work fine, but if I try using the ODBC things start breaking with the same error as initial.

Comment: The /Package /Project thing wasn't working for me. Didn't have a tmp folder (????), and wasn't seeing where that kind of thing was being held.

Comment: The ODBC is using different credentials than the other two (Windows Authentication/Domain account vs managed credentials). Could that be something?

Comment: Sorry, the path there is wherever you have your project hosted. If you right click on the solution node, there should be an Open Folder in File Explorer choice. From there, the .ispac will be in the bin\Development folder

Comment: Oh yes, the password could be the culprit - what is the project's protection level (right click the ssis project node and Common Properties -> Project, Security, ProtectionLevel. Also, when you're running from command line - is that the same machine you're developing on? I've ran into issues with point differences in MySQL drivers ages ago so might make sure you have exact match (although that resulting in a metadata exception, not what you're seeing)

Comment: Also, noticed that VS is running in 32 bit? Added a 32 bit system DSN with the same name, and retried with dtexec in both 32 & 64

Comment: ProtectionLevel is set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey. And yup, command line is being run on the same VM.

Comment: So EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey means anything that could be sensitive is stored in the SSIS package's xml as encrypted text. It uses some attribute of the AD account of the person creating the package as the key so you never provide an explicit password/key for this. As long as the person running the SSIS package is the same as the creator, magic happens and it should have no issue retrieving the credentials.

Comment: Ah, got the /Package /Project thing to run - same error. Should have known that path.

Comment: Got it - and yeah I'm the one creating the package and running, so should be good?

Comment: Good insofar as that shouldn't be the culprit. ;) If you specify `/rep eiw` errors, information, warnings does anything new pop up? Can you verify line 2 of dtexec matches the version of the drivers you've installed and the version of SSIS you've developed the packages for? What ODBC drivers are you dealing with?

Comment: ODBC driver that I'm using is the iSeries Access ODBC Driver - A/S400 connector. From what I can tell, everything is installed as 64 bit. I could go through the process of installing SSIS as 32 if that may help? Does running dtexec use different drivers than pressing "Play" in VS?

Comment: SSIS is already installed with both 32 and 64 bit variants. From a command prompt, type `where dtexec.exe` and you'll get something like 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe  The order of listing is the order of default invocation so if I wanted to run the 64 bit, I'd have to provide the explicit path to the \program files\ variant

Comment: Yup, so I've tried running both ways there. That's what I'm flipping to run between 32 and 64. Both give the same errors

Comment: Hitting Play reflects the settings in Project->Configuration Properties, Debugging but generally nah, it's just dtexec /file for package deployment model and dtexec /Package for package deployment model. I suppose a quick test would be to to hit Debug, Start without Debugging (Shift-F5) and see whether that works. That would be a non-debugger wrapped session

Comment: FWIW, I [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssis/topusers) a lot of SSIS questions and you are doing an excellent job of staying engaged on this your first question as well as stumping me ;)

Comment: Appreciate that - actually noticed that on some of the other questions I've looked at, you're on all those as well! Sincerely appreciate the help. Yesterday I got frustrated and pretty much nuked everything and will be picking this back up Monday. More info then...

Comment: Okay back at it...and now the error is happening when I run Play. Progress? Updated above with the full output from running the package, and the result. It says the ODBC source runs (green checkmark), but also returns a fatal error.

Comment: Another thought...technically the ODBC driver is a Windows 7.1 program. Do I need to set anything in VS or SQL to be 7.1 compatible or something like that? idk. Just thinking out loud.

And for reference, this is a website that shows exactly what I'm doing (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4049/export-data-from-ibm-db2-iseries-to-sql-server/).

Comment: Oookay...more information for you here. So I originally built the package on a Server 2012, then stopped using the server because I couldn't get PowerShell installed onto it. Never had the job scheduled, just where I initially dev'ed it on. Just went over to that VM again...it runs fine from play, and if I go Ctrl+F5...it says it can't run because Server 2017 is not properly installed. Not sure if relevant.

Comment: Server 2017 is not properly installed, like "To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard edition of Integration Services or higher" or something about the Execute SQL Task is not registered or something like that?

Comment: That or you have VS 2012 installed. Multi-version deployment didn't become a "thing" for Visual Studio until SQL Server/VS 2016? Oh, or VS is using the "wrong" version of dtexec to run the package in debug mode as it thinks it's a 2017 project model

Comment: TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

Failed to start project

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Cannot execute the package. The SSIS Runtime for "SQLServer2017" is not properly installed.
Reinstall the SSIS Runtime for "SQLServer2017".
Technical details: DTEXEC.EXE for "SQLServer2017" not found. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Comment: That's what I'm getting on the old one - only VS installed is 2019 actually. In a perfect world I'd just forget about that VM in general and get this up and going on the Server 2019...but...I guess if that's the only place I can get it running...then that's that.

It is SQL Server 2008 R2 on that bad boy installed, so even more fun versioning things

Answer (score 1):

Well. Figured it out.

Turns out it all came down to versioning. I was using a version of IBM iAccess ODBC that had issues with Windows 10. Upgraded to the latest version and it worked.